# C26444 Avoid unnamed objects with custom construction and destruction (es.84)

Tags: c++, class, vector, return

Can anyone help me solve the problem?? Before when I had only one method for class, which was void *show(vector &list, string &filter)*, get&display functions were in it, then i decided to split those functions into *vector get() & void display()* but when i return a new modified vector from *vector get()*  the error appears:

C26444  Avoid unnamed objects with custom construction and destruction (es.84).

Here's a short code example for realization:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Test
{
//variables
};

class Base
{
public:
    virtual vector<Test>get(vector<Test>& list, string& filter) = 0;
    virtual void display() = 0;
};
class A : public Base
{
    string a;
    string b;
    vector<Test> aList;

public:
    vector<Test>get(vector<Test>& list, string& filter)
    {
        //modifying info and placing to vector<Test> aList
        return aList;
    }
    void display()
    {
        //show aList
    }
};

int main()
{
    vector<Test> list;
    //define list
    string filter;
    //define filter

    Base* object = new A();
    object->get(list, filter);
    object->display();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably because you're not assigning the result of `object->get`, try putting that in a variable and see if its happen then, or explicitly ignore the output with `(void)object->get` perhaps.

Comment: The warning message described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/c26444?view=vs-2019) indicates that you are needlessly constructing (as part of the return from the `get` method) and destructing an object. The warning is about inefficient usage. Presumably `get` is supposed to return something useful, so it's return value should not be ignored. You can also use `[[nodiscard]]` to add a non-code-analysis warning.

Comment: (void)object-> get, actually helped, although is it the right way to deal with it?

Comment: @tendor, only if you _intend_ to ignore the return value in this case, (void) makes it explicit you intended to throw the value away

Comment: You much better call your `get` method `filter` or `storeFiltered` because you don't use the result. The name `get` does not have a side effect of modifying the object, `get` should be a `const` method.