# What does "C26444 Avoid unnamed objects with custom construction and destruction (es.84)." means in VS2019?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I made a fraction class like this and overloaded operator +=
Fraction Class:

```
class Fraction
{
private:
    int numerator, denominator;
public:
    Fraction Fraction::operator+=(Fraction fraction)
{
    if (this->denominator == fraction.getDenominator())
    {
        this->numerator += fraction.getNumerator();
    }
    else
    {
        this->numerator = (this->numerator * fraction.getDenominator()) + (fraction.getNumerator() * this->denominator);
        this->denominator *= fraction.getDenominator();
    }
    this->reduction();//unimportant 
    return *this;
}
Fraction(double Number)//constructor
{
    this->denominator = 1;
    while (((double)(int)Number) != Number)
    {
        Number = Number * 10;
        this->denominator = this->denominator * 10;
    }
    this->numerator = (int)Number;
    this->reduction();
}
```

but when I used += in main.cpp like this

```
Fraction a(0.25),b(0.125);
a+=b;//C26444 Avoid unnamed objects with custom construction and destruction (es.84)
```

then C26444 occured on the line of "a+=b"

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Perhaps it about you passing the argument to `operator+=` by value. Try using a constant reference (i.e. `Fraction operator+=(const Fraction& fraction)`)?

Comment: Also, there is no need to specify `this->` in your member functions.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I got it,thanks

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Can you be more specified please?

Comment: @OliverShang Get rid of the `this->`.  There is no need for it.  It just clutters up the code, and you save 6 non-essential keystrokes per line.  I am sure the C++ book you're using doesn't have `this->` specified when specifying a member variable or function.

Comment: `if (this->denominator == fraction.getDenominator())` -- could just be: `if (denominator == fraction.getDenominator())`.  Specifying `this->` all over the place is not a good habit to get into, since it indicates the newness of the C++ programmer, and could reflect negatively in things like code reviews.  There are certain cases where `this->` is required, like in templates in some situations, but your case is not one of them.

Comment: Usually `operator+=` returns a reference. Try changing the return type to `Fraction&`.

Comment: Why is `Number` not colored black? In the `+=` operator the argument is better named `other`. Don't name your variables with a Capital letter.

Comment: Why did your search for this error message not result in this page: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59634866/9938317 ChrisMM explains what the reason is of this warning and shows the link to the MS knowledge article. If you return a `const Fraction&` no object is constructed or destructed